# How to change measure to hierarchy in atoti?

Tags: hierarchy, olap, measure, atoti

I have a categorical data (region code) with high ordinal value.

[image]

When I load this dataframe in atoti datastore it is being read as a measure but the data type is an object.
[image]

Hence, ideally it should be a hierarchy.

How can I change a measure to an hierarchy in atoti?

Answer (score 3):

*Disclaimer: I am a developer at atoti*

---

> When I load this dataframe in atoti datastore it is being read as a measure

Loading data into a datastore does not create any measure. It is the cube that you create on this store that creates measures and hierarchies automatically based on the types (because you are in [auto mode](https://docs.atoti.io/0.6.1/lib/atoti.session.html#atoti.session.Session.read_pandas) by default).

> ideally it should be a hierarchy.

Nothing prevents you from creating additional hierarchies and measures. For instance you can create a new hierarchy on any store column like that:

```py
cube.hierarchies["Region Code"] =  [ store["Region_Code"] ]
```

You can also choose at the store creation which columns must be used as a hierarchy by specifying the `hierarchized_columns` arguments.

```py
store = session.read_pandas(... hierarchized_columns=["Gender", "Age", "Region_Code"])
```

You can read more about this parameter in the [read_pandas documentation](https://docs.atoti.io/0.5.1/lib/atoti.html#atoti.session.Session.read_pandas) for instance.

Also note that you don't have to "choose" between making a column a hierarchy or a measure, the same column can be used for both.

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer: I work at atoti.*

One workaround I figured to load the variable as a string an it will be treated a hierarchy.

```
   customer_store = session.read_pandas(
        master_data2,
        store_name="customer_store",types = {'Region_Code' : tt.types.STRING}
    )
    customer_store.head()
```